# reading values through the usartread function

Tags: c, xc8

```
if (val == 3) {
           //USARTWriteChar(USARTReadChar());
        char point = USARTReadChar(); //USARTReadChar
        buff[y] = point;

       if (point == 0x0D) {

            buff[y] = '\0';
            buff[y] = END_STR;
            int c = atoi(buff);
            itoa(aux, c, 10);
```

I need to communicate with the PIC through the serial port and the moment I write a whole number with two or more digits on the computer keyboard, it should return the table of that same number

Comment: Hi, your question is not clear enough. Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question with some example code that illustrate your problem in order to make it clearer and understandable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hard to answer without any code.